# Convert XML to array with attributes names

Tags: php, simplexml

There are noumerous questions on converting XML to array, and simpliest method is as follows:

```
$data = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($dataXml)), 1)));
```

However, I cant get attributes names using this approach, and could not find any questions on SO, explaining how to do it.

Here is part of XML that I have:

```
<Object>
                <attribute name="Surname">Ярош</attribute>
                <attribute name="Name">Анна</attribute>
                <attribute name="Middle name">Григорьевна</attribute>
                <attribute name="Position">Торговый представитель розничных продаж</attribute>
                <attribute name="City">BAIKALSEA Company Иркутск</attribute>
                <attribute name="Division">Отдел продаж</attribute>
                <attribute name="Department">Продажи</attribute>
                <attribute name="Email">yarosh@baikalsea.com</attribute>
                <attribute name="MobPhone">79149274726</attribute>
                <attribute name="WorkPhone">-</attribute>
                <attribute name="Manager">Нет</attribute>
                <attribute name="HonoredWorker">Нет</attribute>
                <attribute name="Login">yarosh@baikalsea.com</attribute>
                <attribute name="Character">Пользователь</attribute>
        </Object>
```

And here is what I get converting it with encode/decode and simpleXml:

[image]

As you can see 'name' attribute and its value is lost. I need those `name` attributes and their values as well.  Pls any help appreciated.

Comment: can you show what is expected output?

Comment: Any array that has name="Login" (etc.) and value of xmlElement.

Comment: I have a more fundamental question: **why do you need this?** SimpleXML gives you access to all the content of the XML; if you want to use that data for something, traverse it with that. You will *always* lose data trying to convert XML into an array, because the data model of XML is fundamentally different from any array.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally [found](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php) function, that converts XML to object, preserving namespaces, attributes, childs and so on:

```
function xmlObjToArr($obj) { 
        $namespace = $obj->getDocNamespaces(true); 
        $namespace[NULL] = NULL; 

        $children = array(); 
        $attributes = array(); 
        $name = strtolower((string)$obj->getName()); 

        $text = trim((string)$obj); 
        if( strlen($text) <= 0 ) { 
            $text = NULL; 
        } 

        // get info for all namespaces 
        if(is_object($obj)) { 
            foreach( $namespace as $ns=>$nsUrl ) { 
                // atributes 
                $objAttributes = $obj->attributes($ns, true); 
                foreach( $objAttributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue ) { 
                    $attribName = strtolower(trim((string)$attributeName)); 
                    $attribVal = trim((string)$attributeValue); 
                    if (!empty($ns)) { 
                        $attribName = $ns . ':' . $attribName; 
                    } 
                    $attributes[$attribName] = $attribVal; 
                } 

                // children 
                $objChildren = $obj->children($ns, true); 
                foreach( $objChildren as $childName=>$child ) { 
                    $childName = strtolower((string)$childName); 
                    if( !empty($ns) ) { 
                        $childName = $ns.':'.$childName; 
                    } 
                    $children[$childName][] = xmlObjToArr($child); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return array( 
            'name'=>$name, 
            'text'=>$text, 
            'attributes'=>$attributes, 
            'children'=>$children 
        ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have fundamentally the wrong approach. Rather than trying to create one function that can express all possible contents of an XML document in one array, use the APIs provided by SimpleXML to *extract the data you need for your particular task*.

Given your example input, a useful output might be an associative array of key-value pairs, like this:

```
Array (
    [Surname] => Ярош
    [Name] => Анна
    [Middle name] => Григорьевна
    [Position] => Торговый представитель розничных продаж
    [City] => BAIKALSEA Company Иркутск
    [Division] => Отдел продаж
    [Department] => Продажи
    [Email] => yarosh@baikalsea.com
    [MobPhone] => 79149274726
    [WorkPhone] => -
    [Manager] => Нет
    [HonoredWorker] => Нет
    [Login] => yarosh@baikalsea.com
    [Character] => Пользователь 
)
```

Which can be achieved with a simple loop over a SimpleXML element:

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$parsed_attributes = [];
foreach ( $sx->attribute as $attribute_element ) {
    $parsed_attributes[ (string)$attribute_element['name'] ] = (string)$attribute_element;
}

print_r($parsed_attributes);
```

If you don't know in this part of the application how you're going to use the data, keep it as a SimpleXMLElement, and give the rest of your code the power of that API. If you want to store it to use later, use `->asXML()` and store it back in XML form.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for converting XML to an array. For example an API that accepts unpredictable inputs, where the structure or even the language is not known, and tag, text and attributes are all required. Its useful and convenient to be able to convert it to an array for passing to a handler in a consistent format that then processes business logic. Sadly, the json_decode(json_encode()) 'hack' is limited in that it extracts text OR attributes but not both.

Comment: @Dave That sounds like a case where you want to just pass the SimpleXMLElement; at some point, you've got to actually inspect that structure, and the object will give you more information about that than all but the most verbose array representations.

Comment: In my particular case the storage mechanism is JSON, so I have to do a conversion to array in order to json_encode() it (hence the reason Im on this page!). Its annoying that the built in function will handle tag and text, or tag and attributes, but not attributes and text, requiring a potentially convoluted recursive method.

Comment: @Dave The only two universal, lossless ways I know to convert XML to JSON are a) as a string; or b) by describing every tag and every attribute in the DOM structure in a way that would be extraordinarily verbose and completely useless for anything other than recreating the original XML anyway. Other than that, you have to make some assumptions about the data you're storing - Do you care about the order of sequences like `<foo /><bar /><foo />`? Do you care about the position of text nodes relative to elements, like `foo <a /> bar <b /> baz`? Do you care about namespaces? Comments? etc etc